# Retrieving a standard base64 field from Lightning Component causes internal server error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, base64

In a component, I'm returning a list of `ContentNote` from the server and displaying the records' data in an `aura:iteration`.

Including `ContentNote.Content` (a base64-type field) in the return from the server-side controller causes an internal server error:

```
return [SELECT Content, Title, CreatedDate FROM ContentNote WHERE Id IN :noteIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```

However, if I remove the `Content` field, then the internal server error isn't thrown, and the component inits and renders fine:

```
return [SELECT Title, CreatedDate FROM ContentNote WHERE Id IN :noteIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) states "A server-side action can return any object containing serializable JSON data."

I suspect this is because there's a Salesforce issue serializing the base64 `Content` field to JSON, but I only know for certain that including the field in the response cause the error.

Is there a specific approach to retrieving a base64 field from the server? I would prefer to keep the attribute in the component a `List<ContentNote>`, but I can move to a wrapper class that returns the `Content` field decoded as a string if that's the only workaround.

Comment: How about returning a string using JSON.serialize() and then using JSON.parse at the front end ?

Comment: I wanted to see first if there was a way to pass in the base64 data as part of a record - I ended up having to do something similar to your suggestion - separating the `Content` data from the record, decoding it to a string server-side, and then passing it to the component separately from the records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way to directly return the base64 field as part of the `ContentNote` record.

I ended up having to use the workaround in the question - omitting the base64 field from the query, and returning the list of records without that field - and then decoding the base64 field using `.toString()`, and passing it separately to the client side as a string...